# Deduplication based on a Data Extension field

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

Our client stores its customers' information in a DE called **Customers**. A field called *IsMember* describes whether the customer is a member or not. The email field in this DE is not the subscriber key. Each customer has another Id that is unique. So, more than one customer can share the same email address.

From now on, they would like to treat their customers differently based on this field. The emails are personalized and the AMPScript decides what to write to each customer based on their membership status, so that part is not a problem.

What they would like to do is to deduplicate emails when they not members and not deduplicate them when they are. But this is a policy one decides in the **Send Email Activity** or the **User-Initiated Email**.

Of course, there is a manual way of handling this and that is to have two different sends for each marketing email. But this can be quite a time-consuming task and is easy to forget.

Is there a simpler workaround to address this need?

**Update**: Sorry for not mentioning this. But our client has no SQL knowledge and would like to take over the email send tasks. So I am trying to prepare everything for them with little coding skills as possible.

Comment: IMHO this can/should be solved with SQL, deduplicating records and outputting into a new sendable DE. Why isn't this a viable solution?

Comment: @LukasLunow but on that destination sendable DE we again have to choose a single strategy between deduplicating or not. So a single DE would probably not suffice?

Comment: @TammerSalem - the reference you provide is for Core only, and not for SFMC

Comment: @LukasLunow - thanks for pointing out - this is MC not Core (my mistake!) - I'll delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use two SQL queries to handle this?

You can deduplicate non members using something like:

```
SELECT

ContactID AS 'ContactID',
IsMember AS 'IsMember '

FROM
(SELECT DEST.ContactID , DEST.IsMember,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEST.IsMember ORDER BY DEST.CreationDate DESC) 
        AS Row

    FROM Customers DEST WHERE DEST.IsMember = 'false'
 ) as s
 WHERE row=1
```

And then use another SQL query to get all contatcs that are members.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this. I updated the question. Our client has no SQL knowledge and would like to take over the email send tasks. So I am trying to prepare everything for them with little coding skills as possible.

Comment: Your solution works great, except my client is nowhere near SQL savvy I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh okey. I think it would be touchy without coding. Especially because deduplicating is not available on Journey Builder, otherwise it would have been easy on a journey.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, our client has purchased the Marketing Cloud before realising that it is not quite the drag-n-drop tool they expected it to be. So, I am doing my best to make everything simpler for them except, they would like to do new stuff all the time, which are completely doable to me but on every small occasion now, they would like to be able to do the same without bothering with coding. Have you ever had such clients and if so, how have you been handling them?

Comment: Trust me, it is the case for mostly all clients. In my opinion, SQL is inescapable when using SFMC. Exept for really simple use cases with no complex requirements.  Usually, I have a hard time in the beginning explaining this to my clients and at the end they just accept it and get used to it :)

Comment: Still, I take time with my clients to gather their needs and then normalize data on the data model. This way, it is easy for them to create audiences using Data Filter.

Comment: @Disasterkid Why not just do a filter on member/nonmember and then select 'deduplicate'' option in the send? Then it will only send to unique emails in that filtered audience

Answer (score 0):

I think Rachid made an excellent suggestion with his query.

You could also break it up into several queries, add them to an automation, and they both add the right subscribers to a target DE.

In this case your automation would contain one query for deduplicating (i.e. what Rachid shared), and one to get remaining subscribers and append those.

However, since you mentioned your client doesn't have SQL knowledge, why not propose a drag-and-drop alternative like [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-24) to segmented / create targeted lists?